# CSS Allow Free Placement of Div's, Not Rows

Tags: html, css, alignment, rows

I am trying to achieve something like this with CSS

[image]

But instead I am getting this with my current CSS code

[image]

How would I go about getting the boxes to simply "fall" below one another without looking like they are in horizontal rows like the second picture using CSS?

Comment: Could you please provide your code so that we may troubleshoot your issue? A JSfiddle would even be ideal.

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: You could display the items in vertical columns rather than horizontal rows.

Comment: Just at a glance it looks like each row is a parent div for the three times. Looks like you need less structure or instead of rows across use columns going up and down. Agreeing with @MathewMacLean above.

Comment: Study the layout of Pinterest and you'll find what HTML structure they are following. Also, there's a jquery plugin: http://masonry.desandro.com/ - which you might find useful.

Comment: @Veera, it looks like j08691 beat you to that link. (;

Comment: @MathewMacLean yeah, better luck next time to me. :)